# cassandra access from external ip

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have tried to set these in cassandra.yaml:

1. rpc_address: 192.168.1.xx
   listen_address: 192.168.1.xx
   broadcast_address: 192.168.1.xx
2. rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
   listen_address: 192.168.1.xx
   broadcast_address: 192.168.1.xx

in both cases, i can only access from localhost (127.0.0.1)

but when i look at the nodetool status
it shows this

[root@localhost conf]# nodetool status

--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.1.xx  1.23 MB    256          100.0%            cedb8433-a3b3-4fb4-bee7-dae6174712ef  rack1

what to do to set it correctly for external access?

Comment: **Important:** After changing properties in the cassandra.yaml file, you must restart the node for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

In the cassandra.yaml, set the listen_address to the private IP address of the node, the broadcast_address to the public address of the node and rpc_address to "0.0.0.0"

Please take a look [How to configure cassandra for remote connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133127/how-to-configure-cassandra-for-remote-connection)
and [Can't connect to cassandra node from different host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758795/cant-connect-to-cassandra-node-from-different-host)

Hope this helps!

Thanks