# How to Check If I Can Connect to Cassandra Remotely Without Using Telnet

Tags: windows, cassandra, windows-server-2012-r2

I read a question with answer
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758795/cant-connect-to-cassandra-node-from-different-host)

Quoted from there is:

> You can ensure this by using "telnet thecassandrahost 9042" from the remote machine, it should not work.

He said that I can ensure by using telnet from the remote machine.
My question : Is there a way to ensure other than using telnet?
Im using Windows Server 2012 R2

Thanks.

Comment: Basically, you need to check if there is socket listening to port 9042. Hence, except from `telnet`, there is various commands such as `netstat`, `ping`, etc. Depend on your OS, you can use corresponding command.

Comment: `nc -z host 4092` in linux fwiw